# Adding a CSS, JS and HTML code to a block

Tags: 7

Using Drupal 7.2 I've successfully added a Google Adsense banner to [my website](http://preferans.de) by creating a new block with **admin/structure/block/add** and puting Google's code as "raw HTML" (added that "raw HTML" format first in **admin/config/content/formats/add**) there:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "XXX";
/* block1 */
google_ad_slot = "YYY";
google_ad_width = 160;
google_ad_height = 600;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Now I'm trying to add another block containg [a Like-button](http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/display/plugins/Social+Plugins) by the russian social network Odnoklassniki.ru:

[image: Like]

My problem is - they want me to add:

Head:

```
<link href="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.odkl-klass, .odkl-klass:hover {background:none;}
.odkl-klass {background: url(/images/128x128.png) no-repeat;}
</style>
```

Body:

```
<a class="odkl-klass-stat" href="http://preferans.de" onclick="ODKL.Share(this); return false;"><span>0</span></a>
```

And call:

```
<body onload="ODKL.init();">
```

How could I do it the best way please? (it would be good not to have it updated every time I update the Drupal version)

When I just try to put all 3 pieces listed above into a block (as I did for Google banner) - the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link and the script can be added through [drupal_set_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_html_head/6) head

```
drupal_set_html_head('<link href="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>');
```

On clicks are not good practice in drupal. Behaviors are used in stead.

So in your block you can output

```
  <a class="odkl-klass-stat" href="http://preferans.de"><span>0</span></a>
```

You can then set a couple of behaviors in your own script, which you can put in a file and add using drupal_add_js()

```
 Drupal.behaviors.my_module = function (context) {
   // This will load on page load
   ODKL.init();
   // This will attach a click handler to the links
   $('.odkl-klass-stat').click(function() {
   ODKL.Share(this);
   return false;
   }); 
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

http://drupal.org/project/cpn Code per Node is really useful for including Javascript and CSS in seperate text fields.

Have a look

Comment: Interesting, +1 Didn't know it

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty. Put this in the block:

```
<link href="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >window.onload=ODKL.init();</script>
<a class="odkl-klass-stat" href="http://preferans.de" onclick="ODKL.Share(this); return false;"><span>0</span></a>
```

Dirty why? because best practices says to put the css in the `<head>` to be valid HTML, the scripts in the footer for performance reasons, etc. But it will work.

The best way to do it it's enabling PHP filter and using `drupal_add_js, drupal_add_css` functions, etc,  or create a very simple Drupal module, only with a `hook_init` to add the js, css and then the block will contain only the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

For Adsense:

The solution which worked for me is that I used the adsense tags format and then used this format to show ads on the site. Actually I was getting Ads disabled for admin and for other users i was getting the empty ad with space occupied on page but nothing shown. After different tweaks and experiments I got the following code working for me

[adsense:336x280:XXXXXXXXXX]

2nd parameter is width x height
3rd parameter: XXXXXXXXXX denotes the google ad slot/id.

I hope this will help others.

Comment: His problem isn't with adsense. Read the question..

Answer (score 0):

The link and the script can be added through `drupal_set_html_head()` head

```
drupal_set_html_head('<link href="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>')
```

The link and the script can be added through `drupal_set_html_head()` head

```
drupal_set_html_head('<link href="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="http://stg.odnoklassniki.ru/share/odkl_share.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>')
```